# How to configure hostname for `apache22` package on FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, freebsd, hostname

I'm configuring development & test FreeBSD machine on VM.
I installed `apache22` package and restarted. But the daemon does not started with this error:

```
%apachectl start
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for test.box
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
%
```

My hostname is `test.box`. Because this is temporary test box, it has no real domain-name. But I used 2-level name to avoid long time waiting of `sshd` on booting.

However, I searched web, and I modified `/etc/hosts` file like this (I didn't touches this file before):

```
# This is original configuration
#::1                    localhost localhost.my.domain
#127.0.0.1              localhost localhost.my.domain

# New configuration    
::1                     localhost test.box
127.0.0.1               localhost test.box
127.0.0.1               test.box test
```

Now apache fails with this error message:

```
%apachectl start
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using test.box for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
%
```

I don't know what's required now. Please let me know reason and solution of this error.

---- (edit) ----

The permission errors are caused from omission of `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using test.box for ServerName
```

Usually, this is just a warning and not a fatal error. It can be solved by adding the config to your `apache2.conf` file.

```
ServerName yourserver.yourdomain.com
```

I can see there is a permission denied error. Make sure you invoke the startup scripts as super user `root`. Also, make sure there is no other process already listening on apache port (default 80).

Comment: Oh I'm shame on forgetting `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I got found a solution. /etc/hosts file configuration was bad. This is right configuration.

```
# This is original configuration
#::1                    localhost localhost.my.domain
#127.0.0.1              localhost localhost.my.domain

::1                     localhost.test.box localhost
127.0.0.1               localhost.test.box localhost
127.0.0.1               test.box test
```